# Is there equivalent of static library in Go?

Tags: go

### The problem

Linking of our tests is slow. We link ~400 packages every time which takes ~4s.

### Possible solution

Most of the packages come from vendor directory, which changes rarely. It would be awesome to pre-link them into static library and use that (cached) library to speed up linking process.

Not that shared library is not available on Mac's, which is an issue in our case.

Comment: Have a look here: https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Build_modes

Comment: "When compiling multiple packages or a single non-main package,
build compiles the packages but discards the resulting object,
serving only as a check that the packages can be built."

Comment: Also "When compiling packages, build ignores files that end in '_test.go'."

Comment: That quote applies if you are naming packages explicitly. It's not how you normally build a project. In this case if you're just running `go test` then you're already getting cached objects and your speed problem is probably elsewhere.

Comment: There is [golang plugins](https://golang.org/pkg/plugin/) but not sure you want to wrap your depencies into a prebuilt plugin!? Also: Which version of Go are you using? The new version(s) of Go have caching mechanisms for tests and for built depencies.

Comment: What version of Go are you using?